# GRE subject calc III question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Sorry if this is a bit elementary but I forgot lots of my calc III.

Let $A$ be the annulus $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \frac{1}{2} \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 2\}$. Then evaluate $$\iint _A (2x-2ye^{x^2+y^2})dx dy$$

I'd like to use stoke's theorem if possible. However the answer key also stated you can use symmetry of the integral? to see it is zero?. For stokes theorem would I convert this to polar coordinates or? would the angle be from $\frac{- \pi }{2}$ to $\frac{\pi }{2}$ and $r$ from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $2$?

Comment: Do you have some parenthesis in the integral?

Comment: there were not any in the example

Comment: Hint: If I gave you the complicated-looking integral $\int_{-a}^a(\sin^7(x)+x^{19}+\tan^{63} x)\,dx$, could you tell me why this is $0$?

Comment: omg the -a to a????? so I was correct in that it goes from negative pi over two up to pi over two?

Comment: In polar coordinates the angle goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ (or from $-\pi$ to $\pi$) and $r$ from $1/2$ to $2$

Comment: Similarly to the other answers, you can also notice directly that the region is centrally symmetric, i.e. symmetric to the transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$, whereas the integrand flips sign under that transformation. From this the result follows.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because people did not like it or was not well received

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the domain $A$ is symmetric with respect to the line $x=0$, which means that $(x,y)\in A\Leftrightarrow (-x,y)\in A$, then
$$\iint_A x\, dxdy=\iint_A (-x)\, dxdy\implies 2\iint_A x\, dxdy=0.$$
Since the domain $A$ is symmetric with respect to the line $y=0$, which means that $(x,y)\in A\Leftrightarrow (x,-y)\in A$, then
$$\iint_A ye^{x^2+y^2}\, dxdy=\iint_A (-y)e^{x^2+(-y)^2}\, dxdy\implies 2\iint_A ye^{x^2+y^2}\, dxdy=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q$ denote the intersection of the first quadrant with the region of integration. Then
\begin{align}
\int_A (2x - 2y e^{x^2 + y^2}) dxdy &= \int_Q  (2x - 2y e^{x^2 + y^2})
\\&+ \int_Q  (-2x - 2y e^{x^2 + y^2})
\\&+ \int_Q  (-2x + 2y e^{x^2 + y^2})
\\&+ \int_Q  (2x + 2y e^{x^2 + y^2})
\end{align}
The integrals cancel in pairs and the sum is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The first term of the integral is odd in $x$, and the annulus is symmetric under the reflection $x \to -x$.  This implies that it integrates to zero.  A similar argument using the $y$-direction shows that this term integrates to zero as well.  So the whole thing vanishes.

But if you want to use Stokes' Theorem, you would first need to note that the boundary of this annulus consists of *two* curves:

- the circle $r = 2$, with $\theta$ running from $0$ to $2 \pi$, and
- the circle $r = \frac{1}{2}$ with $\theta$ running from $2 \pi$ to $0$.  Note that this last circle is traversed *clockwise* because of the right-hand rule.

To then apply Stokes' Theorem, we need to find a vector field $\vec{v}$ such that $\nabla \times \vec{v} = (2x - 2y e^{x^2 + y^2}) \hat{z}.$  A bit of experimentation shows that we can pick
$$
\vec{v} = e^{x^2 + y^2} \hat{x} + x^2 \hat{y}.
$$
We then have
$$
\iint _A (2x-2ye^{x^2+y^2})dx dy = \iint_A (\nabla \times \vec{v}) \cdot d\vec{a} = \oint_{r = 2} \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{\ell} - \oint_{r = \frac12} \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{\ell}
$$
where we have flipped the sign of the last integral to account for the fact that we are going around it clockwise rather than counter-clockwise.

At this point, it would be simplest to transfer into polar coordinates, for which we can write $d\vec{\ell} = (r d\theta) \hat{\theta}$ for both integrals.  The coordinates and their associated unit vectors will also need to be transformed into polar coordinates.  After all of this, you should find that both of the line integrals above vanish, and so the whole thing vanishes (as we showed via a much simpler argument above.)